# I have created a blog using django and wanted to know whether do we need to store the article as in html format?

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I have created a simple blog which consists below model.

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    article_content = models.TextField()

    ----
    something more here.
    ---
```

views.py

```
def article_detail(request,pk=article_id):
     articles = Blog.objects.get(pk=article_id)
     ----
     return render (request,'article.html',{'article':articles})
```

template

```
{{article.article_content}}
```

But this will simply display the whole content. how to make the different css property to sub-headings and to links.
I want to display something like below. Pls help.

my question is  when i will create the  queryset , it will return whole article page. But there will be different sub-heading also and links. do i make them store as html format?

I want the article something like this.

Heading

contents

sub-heading

sub-heading contents and some images .

Comment: Have you considered storing the CSS and javascript as separate fields on the Blog model?

Comment: @noahandthewhale , i did not . Can you pls give me an example how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the heading is the title field of a blog. So you could create that as a separate model field.

But assuming it is truly in the content portion that you need the output rendered with markup, first the data needs to be stored with markup.  For this, consider who will be inputting the content data. You should do this anyway, but especially if it's non-admin users you need to sanitize the input data before it's saved.  Also consider using something like django-tinymice to make the content input user friendly.

For the output, you will then want to allow html tags in the template using the "safe" filter or {% autoescape_off %}. Consider using a whitelist based sanitizing library such as [bleach](https://github.com/mozilla/bleach) to guard against the may ways you can open yourself up to risk when rendering user input like this.

Comment: yes , I have separate field for the heading. what i am thinking about the sub-heading , links . do i need to store the content as html ?

Comment: The content is probably already allowing html to be stored unless you did anything special. You can check the output of the field by querying it directly against the database. However it is the output which is being autoescaped that will strip all the html tags.  In order to output the html, you will need to turn autoescape off or use the safe filter.  I would strongly  suggest using something like bleach [link](https://github.com/mozilla/bleach) to guard against a lot of ways you can become vulnerable to XSS attacks. I will edit my answer above to include this info too.